# Javascript : print property "name" and "value" in each object in an array using map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So i have this array of objects :

```
const arr = [
{
name: "Bob",
job: "Teacher",
age: 30
},
{
name: "Jack",
occupation: "Developer",
height: "160 cm"
}
]
```

My goal here is to get the property name(for ex : occupation) along with its value dynamically and display both of them using the map function in JS , because am using React to display the data.

(i know there's a way with Object.keys()) , but if there's a way with map it would be better for me

an example of the display for the 1st object would be :

```
name : bob
job : teacher
age : 30
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: you should use both map and Object.keys().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
arr.map(user =>
  <div>
    {Object.keys(user).map(key => (
      <div>{key}: {user[key]}</div>
    ))}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [{
    name: "Bob",
    job: "Teacher",
    age: 30
  },
  {
    name: "Jack",
    occupation: "Developer",
    height: "160 cm"
  }
]

return (<div>
  {
    arr.map(person => (<div>
      {Object.keys(person).map(key => 
        <span>{key} : {person[key]}</span>
      }
    </div>)
  }
</div>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
arr.map(el => {
    return {
        name: el.name,
        job: el.job,
        age: el.age
    }
})
```